# Callback function in JSON Response

Tags: javascript, json

```
var Model= function () {

        function GetData() {    
            // Sending the request and i am getting the response. 

            JsonClientScheduleCareProvider.onload = function () {
                return this.responseText;
            };
            // error handling
            JsonClientScheduleCareProvider.onerror = function (e) {

            };
        return {
            GetApps: GetData,
        }

   }();
```

In the below code I make my JSON Call. If I get the response, I should call the `sendData` function with the response.

```
    var jsonData = Model.GetApps();
    if (!jsonData) {
        Ti.API.warn("JsonData");
        SendData(jsonData);
    }
```

The problem I am facing is before the `jsonData` gets me the response, the `SendData` is called. I need to execute the SendData function only when I get the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait untill your response will be delivered. For this purpose use `callback` function.

Try something like this:

```
var Model= function () {

    function GetData( callback ) {    
        // Sending the request and i am getting the response. 

        JsonClientScheduleCareProvider.onload = function () {
            callback( this.responseText );
        };
        // error handling
        JsonClientScheduleCareProvider.onerror = function (e) {
            callback( null );
        };
    }
    return {
        GetApps: GetData,
    }

}(); 

Model.GetApps( function(jsonData){
   if (!jsonData) {
    Ti.API.warn("JsonData");
    SendData(jsonData);
   }
} );
```

Comment: This and the OP seem to be missing a `}`.